# Range not starting at zero

Tags: python-2.7, range, xlrd

I must be doing something very stupid but I can't work out what it is. I am working with xlrd to read data from an excel file. I am trying to select a column of data by selecting within a range of 787. What I would expect is a range from 0 to 786 but what I am getting is a range starting at 290 and going on to 786. Bellow is my code.

```
import xlrd
sonde_data = xlrd.open_workbook('sonde_name.xlsx')
sonde_data = sonde_data.sheet_by_index(0)
for row in range(sonde_data.nrows):
    print row
    temperature = sonde_data.cell_value(row, 7)
    depth = sonde_data.cell_value(row, 20)
    print depth
```

The result I am getting for print row is a 289, 290,.....,786. I am also only getting the temperature and depth data from 289 to 786. I also tried typing in 787 into the range bit instead of getting the length number of rows but I had the same problem. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers,

Robin

Comment: A stupid question: maybe you just didn't scroll up and see the first N lines? :)

Comment: You say: The result I am getting for print row is a 290, 289,.....,786. --- are you 100% sure about the second number i.e. 289 i.e. it's going backwards??

Comment: Ok that was a mistake in my question. What I am getting is 289, 290, 291, ....786. I have updated the question now :)

Comment: I'd use two different variables for whatever sonde_data is holding Maybe check nsheets first, then store the return in a variable named sheet.  I thought it might be something in the spreadsheet, but the docs say nrows should work how you are using it here.